# Toolbar menu icon is not centered vertically

Tags: android, android-toolbar

[image: screenshot of the application]

I've turned on the "Show layout boundaries" option in Developer Options. From the image I've posted it's obvious that the 'search' icon is not centered vertically.

Code for toolbar and to its style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/AppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/AppBar"/>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AppBar style:

```
<style name="AppBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

The menu is inflated in mainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mMenu == null) {
        mMenu = menu;
        inflateSMenu();
    }
    return true;
}

public void inflateSMenu() {
    mMenu.clear();
    setToolbarTitle(getString(R.string.title));
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_cat, mMenu);
}
```

menu_cat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
      android:id="@+id/action_add_category"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
      android:title="@string/search"
      app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

My quesion is: How can I center the menu icon vertically?

Comment: You can add the `SearchView` in the `Toolbar` layout. This way you do not need to use menus.

Comment: @DevendraSingh Yes, I can, but other pages also have icons on menu

Comment: Add RelativeLayout in your Toolbar layout and add views in your RelativeLayout, set gravity of your views as per your requirement, Here is screenshot, have a look:- http://prntscr.com/djckf8

Answer (score 0):

So you can apply a style to your current app theme like,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>
<item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

And create an `ActionButton` style like

```
 <style name="myActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxWidth">48dp</item>
    <item name="android:width">38dp</item>

</style>
```

Not tested but hope it works.